# What's the difference between gRPC and Beta gRPC classes?

Tags: python, grpc

I have the follow **proto** file that will generate a **_pb2.py** file to be used in python.

```
syntax = "proto3";
service Calculator {
    rpc Add (AddRequest) returns (AddReply) {}
}
message AddRequest{ 
    int32 n1=1;
    int32 n2=2;
}

message AddReply{
    int32 n1=1;
}
```

In **_pb2.py** protoc will generate:

```
...
class CalculatorServicer(object):
  def Add(self, request, context):
    context.set_code(grpc.StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED)
    context.set_details('Method not implemented!')
    raise NotImplementedError('Method not implemented!')

class BetaCalculatorServicer(object):
  def Add(self, request, context):
    context.code(beta_interfaces.StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED)
...
```

I would like to know the difference between the two classes (*CalculatorServicer* vs *BetaCalculatorServicer*) and their usage.

I've seen code using the first class and code using the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the unqualified code elements (and specifically those code elements in the `_pb2_grpc.py` file) rather than the Beta code elements in the `_pb2.py` file. If you are generating your `_pb2.py` and `_pb2_grpc.py` files with a recent version of the code generator (please try to use the absolute latest [`grpcio-tools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grpcio-tools), currently 1.1.3), you should see [doc strings on the Beta code elements in the generated code describing them as deprecated and to be removed in the future](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/8033).

[Our examples](http://www.grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html) show the current intended use of the generated `_pb2` and `_pb2_grpc` modules.